# How to wait for user's action on Mac OS?

Tags: c, pthreads, getchar, getch

I'm coding a multithreaded command-line tool for Mac OS using pthreads. I've got four threads producing lots of output. They're all doing the same work. When one of them finds the needed answer, it sets a global variable `var` to 1 and exits. While all threads are working, `main` is performing a for loop, just instead of `join`ing these threads. The loop looks like that: `while(!var);`. When `var` is set to 1 this loop stops.

After the loop all threads are being killed. Then I want to wait for user's input and exit (something like "Press Enter to exit..."). I tried to use `getchar()` while lots of Internet sources suggest using `getch()`, but there's no `getch()` on Mac OS, right?

The problem is, when I run this app just by double-clicking the app's icon to run it without starting Terminal first, it works OK until the answer is found. Unfortunately, it doesn't wait. It just says something like `process terminated` (it's OK, the program finishes successfully and `return`s 0) and that's all. If I run it from Terminal, it's all the same. It finishes OK, then command prompt is shown.

How do I wait for user's input (like "Press Enter to exit...") in Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    // Any Key will work actually
    system( "read -n 1 -s -p \"Press Enter to exit...\"" );
    return 0;
}
```